# Definition of 'tm' must be imported from module 'Darwin.C.time' before it is required

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, sdk

> Definition of 'tm' must be imported from module 'Darwin.C.time' before
>   it is required

---

this error show to me when I use VideoStreemSDK in a .c file on this SDK in my project for play Online video in app, however in demo worked but when I run my project on device see this error ! so I changed library :

```
#include <sys/time.h>
```

to

```
#include "sys/time.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "sys/time.h"
```

and still not working! and I don't know any more :-(

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgW4a.png)

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbxdg.png)

**

### Problem Solved

**

I realized that SDK have a time.h which the same name file in reference has exist. this tow file when I run App has conflicting.
So I change the time.h file to f_time.h  and now I can Run app without error.

Comment: Do you know what file you're actually trying to include? Do you know what file the demo project you're looking at includes? It seems like you're just guessing at the location here, and you're not giving us much to go on.

Comment: the file name is "cmdutils.c" and in demo project is same!

Comment: check pictures plz

Comment: No, I mean make sure you understand what file `time.h` refers to in the demo project and what it refers to in your project.

Comment: in both refers same ! I don't change this file or any files in SDK ! everything is same like demo!

Answer (score 1):

I realized that SDK have a time.h which the same name file in reference has exist. this tow file when I run App has conflicting. So I change the time.h file to f_time.h and now I can Run app without error. – Mohammad